# How can i get URL in channelActive() method in netty4.x

Tags: java, netty, channel

The url is like `http://url.com/username`.when client connect Server,i need verify the username in channelActive,is this possible?
Thanks

```
public class Handler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
   @Override
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
       //NOT HERE
   }
   @Override
   public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
       //1. get username
       //2. do some queries with username
   }
```

**EDIT:**
I tried with two handlers to get the Object,but still not working.

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>() {
        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            DB.insert(msg);//insert msg to DB
        }
    });
    pipeline.addLast(new MyHandler());



public class MyHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    DB.get();// get msg from DB
    ctx.fireChannelActive();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `/username` is part of HTTP request and in order to get it, you need to read bytes from the channel. Without reading bytes from the channel you can't get the username as this info is not available yet.

So in other words - you can get username only after your channel is active and you read some bytes from the channel.

Comment: I tried with two ChannelInboundHandlers ,but still not working.is there other way to get the Object  @Dmitriy Dumanskiy